# Is it possible to read an excel file through code in a sandbox solution - SharePoint Online

Tags: infopath, sharepoint-online, custom-list, sandbox-solution, excel-services

On a SharePoint Online environment, I have an Infopath based list with Attachment enabled.
When an excel file is attached during a new item creation on this list, I want to have an event receiver that reads the content of the attached excel file and do some activity based on further business logic.

My question is this even possible considering all the restrictions of a sandbox solution ? I'm aware that Excel Services and File I/O streaming is not supported by sandbox solution, so what are the other options am I left with.

Comment: You can still create workflows using SharePoint Designer.  What type of business logic are you trying to implement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a developer but if it is possible to save the file to a library using your sandbox solution then you could access the contents using Excel REST.  I know this is part of Excel Services but as it is client-side I would be surprised if you could not do it from the sandbox?